# How to get DDE server to work in python 3?

Tags: python, pywin32, dde

In 2015 I have posted a question on SO how to [Create DDE server in python and send data continously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152460/create-dde-server-in-python-and-send-data-continuously). The answer and code posted by JayleoPlayGround to that question back then worked flawlessly in python 2.7 and I have used it until recently.

As Python 2 is no longer actively supported from January 2020, I want to move my code to python 3. I have installed pywin32 (version 227) using pip on python 3.7.6 and tried to use the same code as before:

```
# coded by JayleoPlayGround
# use Portable Python 2.7.5.1 + pywin32-214

import time
import win32ui, dde
from pywin.mfc import object


class DDETopic(object.Object):
    def __init__(self, topicName):
        self.topic = dde.CreateTopic(topicName)
        object.Object.__init__(self, self.topic)
        self.items = {}

    def setData(self, itemName, value):
        try:
            self.items[itemName].SetData( str(value) )
        except KeyError:
            if itemName not in self.items:
                self.items[itemName] = dde.CreateStringItem(itemName)
                self.topic.AddItem( self.items[itemName] )
                self.items[itemName].SetData( str(value) )


ddeServer = dde.CreateServer()
ddeServer.Create('Orbitron')
ddeTopic = DDETopic('Tracking')
ddeServer.AddTopic(ddeTopic)

while True:
    yourData = time.ctime() + ' UP0 DN145000001 UMusb DMfm AZ040 EL005 SNNO SATELLITE'
    ddeTopic.setData('Tracking', yourData)
    win32ui.PumpWaitingMessages(0, -1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

When running the above code in python 3.7.6 and using pywin32 (version 227), the external DDE client application that I interface with is able to connect to the DDE server, but the data string is not received correctly. As described before, if I am using Python 2.7 with pywin32 (version 214) this works fine however.

As there are no error messages shown I am lost what the problem is under python 3. I tried all available pywin32 versions for this python version (222 to 227) without success. Any ideas on how to get this to work would be much appreciated.